# How to change the medium breakpoint in Foundation 5

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation-5

I'm new to Foundation and need to change the medium mediaquery breakpoint from 45em to 48em throughout a site that's been built with Foundation 5. I've scoured the source .scss and .js files for "45" and "medium" and have changed the "ranges" values in _settings.scss which appears to be the source of all subsequent calculations.

```
$small-range: (0em, 48em); // 0 - 720 (now 768)
$medium-range: (48.063em, 64em); // 721 (now 769) - 1024
$large-range: (64.063em, 80em); // 1025 - 1280
$xlarge-range: (80.063em, 90em); // 1281 - 1440
$xxlarge-range: (90.063em, 99999999em); // 1441+
```

However, after recompiling and clearing browser caches the breakpoint still happens at 45em.  Is there somewhere else I need to go to change something. I must say I'm finding Foundation very complicated to work with.

Any advice (apart from use another framework or none at all ;) ) would be very welcome.

Comment: Try adding `!important` to all property.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change it in foundation.css.
search for @media screen and .. in foundatuon.css or foundation.min.css whatever you are using and change the breakpoint there also.